# How to use PS4 controller's audio output via Bluetooth on PC?

Tags: pc, ps4, controllers, audio-hardware

When the PS4 controller is connected via the USB cable to the PC, it can be used as an audio device if I plug my headphones into the controller.

Is it somehow possible to use them as an audio device, when I connect the controller via Bluetooth? They can output the sound transmitted via Bluetooth when they're used on a PS4, I would guess that it is somehow possible.

If not via plain Bluetooth, might it work with the USB adapter made by Sony?

Important: It is not meant for remote play. I want to play PC games with it.

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

According to [anecdotal evidence by a reddit user](https://www.reddit.com/r/SteamController/comments/95yh3e/til_you_can_use_a_dualshock_4_controller_as_an/e3wp72t/) and [an Amazon review of the adapter](https://www.amazon.com/review/R3LBLTQO0ND9MN/ref=cm_cr_srp_d_rdp_perm?ie=UTF8), it only works with the official Sony adapter.

There are other Amazon reviews mentioning the [default Windows sound changing when it is plugged in](https://www.amazon.com/review/R25PW2WYX9DC4K/ref=cm_cr_srp_d_rdp_perm?ie=UTF8); I would take this to be further evidence the adapter works.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply! I hoped that it might be possible without the adaptor, as it is absolutely overpriced in my oppinion.

Comment: Yeah it seems like quite a bit for a USB bluetooth dongle. I'm not seeing much evidence to the contrary unfortunately; nor does it sound like the adapter experience is better in a lot of ways. Lots of complaining about issues introduced when using it instead of normal Bluetooth or USB in this thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/pcgaming/comments/7o38t2/til_if_you_have_a_dualshock_4_plugged_into_your/?ref=share&ref_source=link